# How can I overlay two graphs in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

How can I overlay two graphs in Seaborn? I have two columns in my data I would like to have them in the same graph. How can I do it preserving the labeling for both graphs.

Comment: It's not clear what this question is asking. What kind of graph? You can make many kinds of graphs with seaborn, and the right approach will vary depending on what you're doing. What is the relationship between the variables? What does "preserving the labeling" mean? How do you wish to distinguish the two variables? In any case, to the extent that there is going to be a general answer, it will be an answer about matplotlib, not seaborn.

Comment: (1) any kind of graph (2) of course (3) that the labels are still there. axis labels  of both graphs for example (4) color for example

Comment: As already explained, it depends on what kinds of graph. In this related question I give an example of overlaying ``regplot``s by setting up a ``FacetGrid`` and add layers by ``map()``ing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145924/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

seaborn function that operate on a single Axes can take one as an argument.

For instance, the docs to [`seaborn.kdeplot`](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot) include:

```
ax : matplotlib axis, optional
    Axis to plot on, otherwise uses current axis
```

So if you did:

```
df = function_to_load_my_data()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

You could then do:

```
seaborn.kdeplot(df['col1'], ax=ax)
seaborn.kdeplot(df['col2'], ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thanks, the only downside is the labeling is not for both graphs.

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad well you have the `ax` object, so you can do anything at that point, really.

Comment: How would I add a legend in this case?

Comment: @famargar https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

Comment: At least in Seaborn 0.11, the last plot still overwrites and excludes prior plots

Answer (score 34):

One solution is to introduce a secondary axis:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sb.regplot(x='round', y='money', data=firm, ax=ax)
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    sb.regplot(x='round', y='dead', data=firm, ax=ax2, color='r')
    sb.plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: it would probably help to have a legend in this case. to do so you can use the label-parameter in seaborn functions but apparently you need to call plt.legend() after each plotting function

Answer (score 3):

The data is about Private vs Public collage data but works, as we can see we load all the global parameters to a seaborn object and later we map the charts to the same pane.

```
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('College_Data',index_col=0)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df,hue='Private',palette='coolwarm',size=6,aspect=2)

g.map(plt.hist,'Outstate',bins=20,alpha=0.7)
```

[See Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7mMM.png)