# Adding horizontal and vertical lines and colorbar to seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I would like to use *kernel density estimate* of `seaborn`.

**First** I would like to add a colorbor for the main plot.

**Second** I would like to add horizontal line to the joint probability distribution to show the 68%, 98% confidence levels and another line which shows the true value

**Third** I also would like to remove the legend in the plot, considering the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_context("paper")
# Generate a random correlated bivariate dataset
rs = np.random.RandomState(5)
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x1, x2 = rs.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T
x1 = pd.Series(x1, name="$X_1$")
x2 = pd.Series(x2, name="$X_2$")

# Show the joint distribution using kernel density estimation
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0, color="r")
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Not easily possible (although the density values are not particularly interpretable anyway).
2. These are matplotlib objects, you can add any additional plot elements you want to them.
3. `stat_func=None`, as is shown [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do any of those per [doc](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).

1. *I would like to add a colorbor for the main plot.*

That's no an option with `jointplot`. Colorbars are only available with [`heatmap`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), [`clustermap`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), and [`interactplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.interactplot.html)

2. *I would like to add horizontal line to the joint probability distribution to show the 68%, 98% confidence levels and another line
   which shows the true value*

Not an option as well, the closest you can come to that is [overlay two graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn)

3. *I also would like to remove the legend in the plot*

I'm assuming you're talking about the `pearsonr` and `p` values. Those aren't legends and no documentation to show a way to remove them.

Comment: I am sure there should be a way to access the axes of these plots and manipulate them accordingly but I don't know how?!

Comment: There is a way if you change the underlying code, but other than that there isn't much room for customization with `seaborn`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to change the  underlying code as you said.