# How To Plot Multiple Histograms On Same Plot With Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histplot

With matplotlib, I can make a histogram with two datasets on one plot (one next to the other, not overlay).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = [random.randrange(100) for i in range(100)]
y = [random.randrange(100) for i in range(100)]
plt.hist([x, y])
plt.show()
```

This yields the following plot.

[image]

However, when I try to do this with seabron;

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot([x, y])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset
```

So then I try to add some color values:

```
sns.distplot([x, y], color=['r', 'b'])
```

And I get the same error. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn) on how to overlay graphs, but I would like these histograms to be side by side, not overlay.

And looking at the [docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot) it doesn't specify how to include a list of lists as the first argument 'a'.

How can I achieve this style of histogram using seaborn?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you may want to try something this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for a in [x, y]:
    sns.distplot(a, bins=range(1, 110, 10), ax=ax, kde=False)
ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
```

Which should yield a plot like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Looks like you want 'seaborn look' rather than seaborn plotting functionality.
For this you only need to:

```
import seaborn as sns
plt.hist([x, y], color=['r','b'], alpha=0.5)
```

Which will produce:

[image]

**UPDATE** for `seaborn` v0.12+:

After `seaborn` v0.12 to get seaborn-styled plots you need to:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme()  # <-- This actually changes the look of plots.
plt.hist([x, y], color=['r','b'], alpha=0.5)
```

See [`seaborn docs`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html) for more information.

Comment: This looks like an overlay, but is there a way to get the bars side by side instead of superimposed?

Comment: How can you create a histogram in seaborn from distributions, x and y in your example, that are too large to hold in memory?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew This is a good question, but best to be addressed as a separate one (i.e. you need to ask "a new question").

Comment: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plot'.

Comment: In your second chunk of code (giving the histogram a "seaborn look"), is there any particular reason you imported the seaborn package before running ```plt.hist()```?

Comment: The reason for importing `seaborn` was to get a "seaborn look" (while it was being imported it applied its own styles to `matplotlib` stylesheets). Also note that recent version of `seaborn` (require additional command). I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 8):

Use `pandas` to combine `x` and `y` into a DataFrame with a name column to identify the dataset, then use [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with `multiple='dodge'` and `hue`:

```py
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

random.seed(2023)  # to create the same plot each time
x = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)]
y = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)]

df = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'value': x, 'name': 'x'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'value': y, 'name': 'y'})
])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(
    data=df, x='value', hue='name', multiple='dodge',
    bins=range(1, 110, 10), ax=ax
)

sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

#### `df`

```
     value name
  0     49    x
  1     89    x
  2     57    x
  3     49    x
  4     40    x
...
195     15    y
196     70    y
197     38    y
198     75    y
199     29    y
```

Comment: Why `for _ in range()` instead of `for i in range()`? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/3364859

Comment: `_` because the `i` isn't being used in the comprehension. We're calling the function `random.randrange(100)` without using the values generated by the range function, which is why the throw-away variable is more appropriate (to indicate we're _not_ using the variable `i`). Packages were reordered to meet [PEP8 import guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). "Imports should be grouped in the following order: (1) Standard library imports. (2) Related third party imports ... You should put a blank line between each group of imports." @marianoju

Comment: If your datasets are different size and you'd like to compare their individual probabilities, add `stat='probability', common_norm=False`.