# Seaborn histogram with 4 panels (2 x 2) in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, seaborn

I'm trying to recreate this image using `sklearn.datasets.load_iris` and `seaborn`.  I really like the idea of doing `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then using `seaborn`'s `ax=ax` attribute.  I can't figure out how to recreate this plot: [image]

I checked on stackoverflow and found this but it overlays them [How To Plot Multiple Histograms On Same Plot With Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362624/how-to-plot-multiple-histograms-on-same-plot-with-seaborn)

Here's my code and plot:

```
# Iris Dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

%matplotlib inline 

DF_data = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data, 
                       columns = load_iris().feature_names, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])])

Se_targets = pd.Series(load_iris().target, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])], 
                       name = "Targets")

#Visualizing Iris Data
D_targets = {0: 'Iris-Setosa',
            1: 'Iris-Versicolor',
            2: 'Iris-Virgnica'}

D_features = {0: 'sepal length [cm]',
              1: 'sepal width [cm]',
              2: 'petal length [cm]',
              3: 'petal width [cm]'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 6))

idx_feature = 0

#Plot on 2 x 2 ax object

for i in range(ax.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, ax.shape[1]):
        for idx_target, label_target  in list(D_targets.items()):
            sns.distplot(DF_data.as_matrix()[Se_targets==idx_target, idx_feature],
                         label=D_features[idx_feature],
                         kde=False,
                         bins=10,
                         ax=ax[i][j])        
        idx_feature += 1 

plt.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True, fontsize=8)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

My plot is looking pretty bad:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

In response to @Cel answer, I've achieved this plot but I haven't been able to fix the labels and darken the lines around the plots.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are indexing a numpy array with a boolean series instead of a boolean numpy array.

```
sns.distplot(DF_data.as_matrix()[Se_targets==idx_target, idx_feature],
             label=D_targets[idx_target],
             kde=False,
             bins=10,
             ax=ax[i][j])
```

I agree that this is very unintuitive. As a matter of fact, numpy already tells you that this will be changed in the future:

```
DF_data.as_matrix()[Se_targets==idx_target, 2]
```

> /Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/**main**.py:1: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index

For now, this should work for you:

```
sns.distplot(DF_data.as_matrix()[Se_targets.as_matrix()==idx_target, idx_feature],
             label=D_features[idx_feature],
             kde=False,
             bins=10,
             ax=ax[i][j])
```

This is the complete code:

```
# Iris Dataset
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

%matplotlib inline 

DF_data = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data, 
                       columns = load_iris().feature_names, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])])

Se_targets = pd.Series(load_iris().target, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])], 
                       name = "Targets")

#Visualizing Iris Data
D_targets = {0: 'Iris-Setosa',
            1: 'Iris-Versicolor',
            2: 'Iris-Virgnica'}

D_features = {0: 'sepal length [cm]',
              1: 'sepal width [cm]',
              2: 'petal length [cm]',
              3: 'petal width [cm]'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 6))

idx_feature = 0

#Plot on 2 x 2 ax object

for i in range(ax.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, ax.shape[1]):
        for idx_target, label_target  in list(D_targets.items()):
            plot = sns.distplot(DF_data.as_matrix()[Se_targets.as_matrix()==idx_target, idx_feature],
                         label=D_features[idx_feature],
                         kde=False,
                         bins=10,
                         ax=ax[i][j])
            plot.set_xlabel(D_features[idx_feature])
        idx_feature += 1 

plt.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True, fontsize=8)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  I'm still having trouble with my labels.  I've added my new plot.  I checked the dictionary with the labels and the labels are printing correctly at that spot.

Comment: `label = D_targets[idx_target]` fixes the labels

Answer (score 9):

Or you could do

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris_long = pd.melt(iris, "species", var_name="measurement")
g = sns.FacetGrid(iris_long, hue="species", col="measurement", col_wrap=2, sharex=False)
g.map(plt.hist, "value", alpha=.4)
```

[image]

Comment: how can you make it not say "measurement = " ?

Comment: Also, how can you get the Species labels in the legend?