# How can I overlay lmplot graphs in one?

Tags: python, seaborn

How can I combine two graphs, both using the same data, created by `seaborn` (`lmplot`)?

One is a scatterplot (divided by categories) and another one is a regression line (categories combined).

```
sns.lmplot(x="hole (nm)", y="granule (sum)", data=data1, fit_reg=False,
           hue='area', palette="winter", scatter_kws={"s": 80})

sns.lmplot(x="hole (nm)", y="granule (sum)", data=data1, fit_reg=True,
           palette="winter", scatter=None)

plt.savefig("fig.png", dpi=200)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I overlay two graphs in Seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn)