# How can I overlay 2 dataframes on a seaborn distplot using a for loop?

Tags: loops, overlay, seaborn

I created a loop which creates a sns distplot with all variables in 1 dataframe however I'm trying to overlay a 2nd dataframe with the same columns to compare the differences in distribution.

I've checked out this answer (and others) to no avail : [How can I overlay two graphs in Seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn)

This is what I currently have:

```py
    for i, col in enumerate(mean_loan_data_float.columns):
     plt.figure(i)
     ax= sns.distplot(mean_loan_data_float[col])
     ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
     plt.tight_layout()
     plt.show()
```

My 2nd dataframe is called median_loan_data_float.

What I want is to have mean_loan_data_float AND median_loan_data_float in the same graphs. 
I'm thrown by what to do when I want to have a second for loop.

Comment: `plt.figure(i)` creates a new figure. If you put that into the loop you end up with as many figures as loop runs. `plt.show()` shows the figure(s). Again if you put it into the loop, each plot will be shown indicvidually.

Comment: Could you show a part of your data

Comment: Sorry, the 1st comment solved my issue. Hence the upvote!