# Seaborn plot with shared x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot 2 columns of a dataframe (one as a bar plot and the other as a scatterplot). I can get this working with Matplotlib, but I want it with Seaborn.

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Announced Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
              'Amount Awarded': [12978216, 11582629, 11178338, 11369267],
              'Number of Awarded': [18, 14, 13, 13]})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

sns.scatterplot(x="Announced Year", y="Number of Awarded", data=df, ax=ax2)
sns.barplot(x="Announced Year", y="Amount Awarded", data=df, ax=ax1)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped

plt.title('2016 to 2019 Announcements')
```

[image: This is the image I get, where I can't see the scatterplot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I overlay two graphs in Seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn)

Comment: Nope. That's exactly what I do in my code and doesn't work.

Comment: A `scatterplot` is a numerical plot, a barplot is a `categorical` plot, so it's hardly possible to put them on the same graph. Matplotlib's `bar` and `scatter` are both numerical, so that works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot with shared x-axis using `x=np.arange(0,len(df))` instead of `x="Announced Year"` for *scatterplot*.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

sns.barplot(x="Announced Year", y="Amount Awarded", data=df, ax=ax2, alpha=.5)
sns.scatterplot(x=np.arange(0,len(df)), y="Number of Awarded", data=df, ax=ax1)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped

plt.title('2016 to 2019 Announcements')
```

[image]